# FTP 550 Access is Denied When Full File Path is Used

Tags: unix, ftp, put

When I try to ftp a file from my home directory, I am successful when I just use the file name.  However, using the entire path of the file produces a "550 Access is denied" error.  Does anyone know what might cause this?

put test.file #works fine
put /home/testDir/test.file #access is denied

The file has full read/write/execute access for everyone on my server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the name of the destination file as well, else it tries to put the file at the same path on the server as it is locally:

I mean do this:

```
put /home/user/fred/file.txt   file.txt
```

instead of

```
put /home/user/fred/file.txt
```

which would require that the directory `/home/user/fred` exists on the server and is writeable.

Comment: Thank you very much!  It's the little things that always trip me up.  You're a life saver.

Comment: I fell foul of it myself too once back in 1992 and have never forgotten :-)